# Requirejs not finding third party file

Tags: magento2, requirejs, requirejs-config.js, third-party-library

I'm trying to include Firebase in my website, so I decided to include the dependencies through requirejs. Thing is requirejs can't find my files for some reason.

What I first tried was to load the cdn directly with path:

```
//app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/requirejs-config.js
paths: {
    firebase_app: 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-app.js',
    firebase_analytics: 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-analytics.js'
}
```

And then require it

```
//app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/myTemplate.phtml
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'firebase_app',
    'firebase_analytics'
], function ($, firebase, analytics) {

    const firebaseConfig = {
        ...
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
});
</script>
```

but this just adds an extra .js at the end of the url for some reason:

```
require.js:1895 GET https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-app.js.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

So I tried to remove the file extension in the url, but then requirejs looks for the file inside my project folder ?

```
GET http://siteurl.com/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/fr_FR/@firebase/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I then tried to download the files and place them inside my module directory, under `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/lib`, but I end up with the same results. The one thing I noticed is that the file url seems normal ONLY WHEN the file does not exist:

#### Correct path

```
//app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/requirejs-config.js
var config = {

    paths: {
        firebase_app: 'Vendor_Module/js/lib/firebase-app',
        firebase_analytics: 'Vendor_Module/js/lib/firebase-analytics'
    }
};

//result
GET http://site_url/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/fr_FR/@firebase/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

#### Wrong path

```
//app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/requirejs-config.js
var config = {

    paths: {
        firebase_app: 'Vendor_Module/js/lib/firebase-apppp', //does not exist
        firebase_analytics: 'Vendor_Module/js/lib/firebase-analytics'
    }
};

//result
require.js:1895 GET http://siteurl.com/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/fr_FR/Vendor_Module/js/lib/firebase-apppp.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) 
//actual directory ???
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: i am facing the same issue please help

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using another url defined here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1266 that seems to be working

I still do not understand why what I tried before is not working. If anyone can find what's wrong, please let me know

Answer (score -1):

So, you set this path: *Vendor_Module/js/lib/firebase-app*, your file should be here: *app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/lib/firebase-app.js*

For the "frontend" keyword you can try with "base" or "adminhtml" - it`s related with the scope of the script usage.

Comment: My file is already there. I meant Vendor/Module, not Vendor_Module*